# How to create a neural network with many different values in Matlab?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, matlab

I want to create a neural network in Matlab.

I have 16 import matrices in each iteration,  my import data changes in every iteration and there are more than 100000 iterations. The target is a matrix like [x y z] and is sum of imported data.

Do you have any suggestion for creating this kind of neural network?
any idea where should I start?

Thanks

Comment: Use nprtool if your matlab is for 2014 or later

Comment: I already tried it but it is impossible to define a 1*3 vector or matrice as a target for 3*16 matrice as input.

Comment: the first one is possible but the second one, as I know, is not possible. However there is a solution for this. In machine learning context there is a jargon named Roll and Unroll operation. That's true, you can not do that, you have to change your matrix to vector then feed it to the network. If you can't find a link for understanding Rolling, tell me to provide it :)